# hadoop 2.7.1 - configuration secondary name node

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, amazon-web-services

I am in the process of configuring a hadoop multi nodes env on ubuntu.
5 nodes - master/3 slaves/ and a secondary name node (not CDH/HDP).

I went thru the various post including [Unable to start CDH4 secondary name node: Invalid URI for NameNode address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753800/unable-to-start-cdh4-secondary-name-node-invalid-uri-for-namenode-address)

However, I still have a question: 
Is there a specific configuration of the *-site.xml, *-env.sh or ... or are these files a copy of the namenode ones?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

for those who may have same kind of question the answer is NO